# What is the limit on the number of INSERT statements you can paste into SSMS and run?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am currently creating a stored procedure that populates a table with a list of insert statements so that my DBAs can export the contents of the table to a text file and then paste the statements into SSMS and run (it is to copy data from test environment to live enviroment - I am constricted by the fact the 2 environments cannot see each other, bcp is not configured on the environment

My question is that the table I am going to export could have up to 2,000,000 insert statements. Is there a limit to what can be pasted in and run?

Comment: Sounds very much like wrong tool for the wrong job. Can you not make a case for extract/import of just the data with an appropriate tool e.g. bcp/bulk insert/SSIS?

Comment: You'll want to save the output to a text file, and have your DBA run that text file using `sqlcmd.exe`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> bcp is not configured on the environment

BCP is an `exe` that comes with SQL Server. The default path is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe`

You can refer to my BCP and BULK INSERT script [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/55063/8783).

> I am going to export could have up to 2,000,000 insert statements.

SSMS wont be able to support this. You have to use `SQLCMD`.

Highly suggest you to use BCP or SSIS to do the task.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments (and marked answer) - I am going to go back to the DBAs and explain that this is the wrong approach