# SQL Server - creating a historical data backup

Tags: sql-server, backup

I've run out of space on my SQL Server 2008 Express DB.

i'm creating a "duplicate" SQL Server 2008 Express DB so i can backup my data before i purge my DB so i can start over.  Is there a way in SQL Server to view the DDL text file, so i can easily recreate the empty table before i push data into it?

Also, is there as "easy" way to bulk push data from one table into another once i've created the backup structure?

at first i tried deleting some old rows, but of course that just increases the log file.

Comment: I advise referring to this as an archive rather than a backup. Different communities (such as Finance and IT in particular) have historically used the term *backup* with wildly divergent meanings. Calling something an *archive* avoids the nasty surprise of waking up one morning to discover that your backup was deleted by IT *because it was only a backup, so you must have several more lying around.*

Answer (score 1):

> I've run out of space on my SQL Server 2008 Express DB.

Best is to [script out the schema using SSMS.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/55063/8783) Then

- Take a full backup of your database --or--
- [bcp out the data from the tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/55063/8783). (note: the script will bcp out in native format. Change it to bcp out data in human readable format - by removing `-n`)

Answer (score 0):

[By using SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) or by using [T-SQL script](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/scripts/tsql/copy-list-tables-having-auto-increment-columns-separate-database).

Comment: It would be great if you could add some summary to your answer. Link only answers are not useful in many ways and those links might become broken in future.