# Limit of Generating Script for Schema Only from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Is there a limit on this method? I've tried a 35GB Database and it works, but my question is how about if my Database is like 100-150GB? Will I encounter some error? Or it will work smoothly but a little bit slow because of a large database size?

I'm using the method given by @Kin [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/100840/moving-sql-server-2012-database-to-sql-server-2008-r2/100862#100862)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schema generation will totally depend on the amount of objects (tables, SPs, triggers, indexes, etc) in database.

Schema is just a ***skeleton*** of the database without data.

If you are concerned about using SSMS GUI, you can use [PowerShell - which will definitely scale better - and can be automated easily](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56625/8783) as compared to SSMS GUI.

I have tried scripting out schema of 1TB data warehouse database without any issues (*as I said previously, the more objects you have, the bigger script it will be - and slower too* (better to use PowerShell)).