# Techniques for moving database from Enterprise to Standard Editiion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

I have a SQL Server 2012 Enterprise edition and a `Model` database. On a virtual machine I have installed SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition and want to create a copy of the `Model` database on it.

I have read about the differences between the editions and it seems that no Enterprise-specific features are used in the `Model` database (anyway, I need to test the migration to be sure).

Which is the better way to move the database from the Enterprise to the Standard edition:

- creating full backup and restoring it
- scripting the database as `.sql` file and executing it

Comment: You need to first make sure both are at same SP level after that you can restore backup of model database from 2012 ent to 2012 standard. I am not sure about what would be after affects. I would go with backup and restore

Comment: In terms of keeping the data it would be easier to backup and restore. I did this in the past going from 2012 Enterprise to 2014 Standard and it worked fine. Be sure to run "select * from sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features" to find any enterprise features being used.

Comment: There are [different ways - script out schema, Bcp out data and bulk under it back](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55055/how-to-move-a-database-from-sql-server-2012-to-sql-server-2005/55063#55063) - they are useful for downgradeing. Backup restore is the way to go since you are confident that no enterprise features are being used.

Comment: I also believe it is possible to just copy over the mdf similar to what is described here.   https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3079/downgrade-from-sql-server-enterprise-edition-to-standard-edition/  This may not do what you are looking for but I have used this technique and it worked great for me.