# Migrate database from SQL Server 2008 Enterprise to SQL Server 2014 Standard

Tags: sql-server, migration, compression

I need move database with "data compression" from SQL Server 2008 Enterprise to SQL Server 2014 Standard.

But Standard edition does not support "data compression".

How can I disable "data compression" in database?

I tried this:

```
ALTER INDEX [_Acc13_ByCode_SR] ON [dbo].[_Acc13] 
   REBUILD PARTITION = ALL
   WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE)
```

but still see that compression is enabled:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> I need move database with "data compression" from MS SQL 2008 Enterprise to MS SQL 2014 standard.

Downgrading is always a pain !

If you have a source control for your database, I would suggest you to create the database shell (schema, objects - tables, views, indexes) on the new 2014 standard server.

[BCP out and BULK INSERT from the old server (Enterprise edition) to New 2014 (standard edition) server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/55063/8783).

I would say, rely on T-SQL rather than GUI. From [Disable Compression on a Table or Index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh710073.aspx)

```
-- To disable compression on a table

USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
ALTER TABLE Person.Person REBUILD PARTITION = ALL
WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE);
GO

-- To disable compression on an index

USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
ALTER INDEX AK_Person_rowguid ON Person.Person REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE);
GO
```

Comment: thanks, for link on BCP out and BULK INSERT from the old server (Enterprise edition) to New 2014 (standard edition) server. very usefull

Comment: @das-ich glad that you found it useful. Please upvote/ mark as answer if the answer has answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could always script out the relevant tables and/or indexes by using the following statements. They create the relevant `ALTER TABLE ...` or `ALTER INDEX ...` statements which you can then cut & paste from the output window to the input window and use to reset the compression to **NONE**.

They aren't the prettiest, but they do the job.

#### Table objects

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE [' + ss.name + '].[' + so.name + '] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE)
GO'
       /*,
       so.name,
       ss.name,
       so.xtype,
       so.uid,
       so.status,
       sp.data_compression_desc*/
FROM   sys.partitions       AS sp
       JOIN sys.objects  AS so
            ON  sp.[object_id] = so.[object_id]
       JOIN sys.schemas     AS ss
            ON  so.[schema_id] = ss.[schema_id]
WHERE  1 = 1
       AND sp.data_compression_desc != N'NONE'
```

The ouput will look a bit like this (TEXT):

```
ALTER TABLE [sys].[syscsrowgroups] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE)
GO
ALTER TABLE [sys].[syscscolsegments] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE)
GO
ALTER TABLE [sys].[syscsdictionaries] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE)
GO
ALTER TABLE [DBT].[Database] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE)
GO
```

#### Index objects

```
SELECT 'ALTER INDEX [' + si.name + '] ON [' + ss.name + '].[' + so.name + '] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE)
GO'
       /*>,
       si.name,
       so.name,
       ss.name,
       sp.data_compression_desc*/
FROM   sys.indexes          AS si
       JOIN sys.partitions  AS sp
            ON  si.[object_id] = sp.[object_id]
            AND sp.index_id = si.index_id
       JOIN sys.objects  AS so
            ON  so.[object_id] = si.[object_id]
       JOIN sys.schemas     AS ss
            ON  so.[schema_id] = ss.[schema_id]
WHERE  1 = 1
       AND sp.data_compression_desc != N'NONE'
```

The output will look a bit like this (TEXT):

```
ALTER INDEX [clust] ON [sys].[syscsrowgroups] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE)
GO
ALTER INDEX [clust] ON [sys].[syscscolsegments] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE)
GO
ALTER INDEX [clust] ON [sys].[syscsdictionaries] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE)
GO
ALTER INDEX [CL_UX_Database_ID_DB_NAME_INST_ID] ON [DBT].[Database] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE)
GO
```

You can build upon these scripts and add in all the relevant options for the ALTER INDEX statement.

> Caution: You need enough free space in the database for the decompress to work.

#### Estimate size of decompressed data

With the following script you can create an output which you can then use to query all the objects that have compression turned on:

```
SELECT 'sp_estimate_data_compression_savings @schema_name = ''' + ss.name + ''', @object_name = ''' + so.name + 
       ''', @index_id = ' + CAST(si.index_id AS NVARCHAR(100)) + 
       ', @partition_number = ' + CAST(sp.partition_number AS NVARCHAR(100)) + ' , @data_compression = ''NONE''
GO'
FROM   sys.indexes          AS si
       JOIN sys.partitions  AS sp
            ON  si.[object_id] = sp.[object_id]
            AND sp.index_id = si.index_id
       JOIN sys.objects     AS so
            ON  so.[object_id] = si.[object_id]
       JOIN sys.schemas     AS ss
            ON  so.[schema_id] = ss.[schema_id]
WHERE  sp.data_compression_desc != N'NONE'
```

...which will generate scripts that look at bit like these examples:

```
sp_estimate_data_compression_savings @schema_name = 'dbo', @object_name = 'IDXProperty2', @index_id = 1, @partition_number = 1 , @data_compression = 'NONE'
GO
sp_estimate_data_compression_savings @schema_name = 'dbo', @object_name = 'IDXProperty6', @index_id = 1, @partition_number = 1 , @data_compression = 'NONE'
GO
```

And when you run the above statements against your database, you will get a summary of the expected decompressed data for each object. Following an example output for an object:

[image: sp_estimate_data_compression_savings results]

Good luck!