# Backup & Restore Error in MS SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, sql-server-2016

I have a backup from SQL Server 2016. I want to restore it in my pc but I am getting this error.

> The database was backed up on a server running `version 13.00.1400`.
>   That version is incompatible with this server, which is running
>   `version 11.00.5343`.

I have searched in Google and have try to upload some patches but it's still the same.How can I fix it.

Comment: welcome to the site. what you are getting the error?

Comment: Error states everything. You can't go backwards with restores in SQL Server. You have to update your SQL instance to match to version 13.00.1400. Then only you can restore the backup.

Comment: @SQLPRODDBA I have download the SSMS for update my sql. But I think it was not the solution for my error.

Comment: Only updating SSMS won't work. You have to update your database engine.

Comment: SSMS is really just another client application. It is not part of the DBMS. You will have to install the more recent database engine on your PC to restore this file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  what the poster requests cannot be done.

Comment: @MichaelGreen you mean that I can not use this backup. which other app must I have install for this error.

Comment: @omrcm you must have SQL Server version 13.00.1400 or above installed.

Comment: What @RobertGannon said.

Comment: @RobertGannon here is my sql server info I think this is not the right version     `                                                                                                Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  13.0.15600.2
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools   13.0.1605.86
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)  10.0.10586.0
Microsoft MSXML                        3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer     9.11.10586.0
Microsoft .NET Framework     4.0.30319.42000
Operating System              6.3.10586`

Comment: @omrcm I do not believe Management Studio, Analysis Services Client Tools, DAC, MSXML, IE, .NET, or Windows is the correct software. My assumption is that if you run     `select @@version`    in SQL Server Management Studio against the destination database, you will see that it matches the version number in the error message, which is behind the version used to create the source backup.

Comment: @RobertGannon I can not understand why the result from the query is 11.0.5343. Because I have install sql 2016. And when I start the program its show me that ms sql 2016 is starting

Comment: @omrcm You have installed 2016 Management Studio, not 2016 SQL Server Database Server. You are still trying to take a DVD you burned (backup from newer SQL version) and put it into a cassette player (destination server running older SQL version), and putting on Google Glasses (2016 Mgmt Studio) and retrying still doesn't make your cassette player DVD compatible.

Answer (score 1):

The error message

> The database was backed up on a server running version 13.00.1400. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running  version 11.00.5343.

means that you are having backup of `sql server 2016 RC3` --> `13.00.1400` and you are trying to restore it on your PC which is running `11.00.5343` --> `sql server 2012 SP2 + GDR 3045321 fix`.

Restoring the database from higher version to lower version is not supported using backup restore or attach/detach methods.

A `RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'X:\yourBackupFile.bak'` will give you the major, minor and software version build numbers that you can confirm.

[Downgrading database is a pain](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/55063/8783) !

Best is to install FREE DEV sql server 2016 RTM + CU1 on your PC machine and restore the backup.