# How to restore hundreds of GB database present on SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup

I know that this was not possible as a scenario for SQL Server 2012 -> 2008 but I wonder if MS made any changes here with the 2014 version.

We have SQL Server 2014 version with a fairly large database, We’d like to restore a backup of that database to SQL Server 2008 R2 because that physical machine has more space, RAM,…

I’m getting standard error message when I try to restore backup but I was wondering if there is something else in SQL Server 2014 that I might be missing.

Also, are there any tools like Redgate/SQLSentry that will be of any use while working with databases size of hundreds of GB size?

Comment: You can't go backwards, sorry, and I suspect this will *always* be true - no new magic downgrade feature was introduced in 2014 or 2016. Your options are: (a) create a new empty database and move the schema/data using SSIS, 3rd party comparison tools, etc. or (b) install a 2014 instance on the other server (or upgrade the existing instance).

Comment: This answer [will be useful as well](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/55063/8783).