# Data Migration With Different Schemas

Tags: sql-server, migration

I have a database `DBv1` on a SQL Server, and I want to migrate the data in it to `DBv2` (on the same box, save server). `DBv2` has very similar schema. The only difference in schema is that `DBv2` has one less table, because it is de-normalized.

What would be the most practical way to migrate the data from `DBv1` to `DBv2` given that change in schema, and the need for some transformation?

Is there a tool that would do that for me? Or do I have to script that manually?

For clarification: this is a one-time load only since it is just a migration. By schema here I do not refer to the SQL object with the same name. Rather, I am referring to the structure of the tables. Due to de-normalization, one table is removed, and a new column is added to the parent table that would have the data in the deleted table.

Comment: Since you can't simply restore over DBv2, the answer will be affected somewhat depending on whether this will be a one-time load or a recurring update (Note: Reloading from scratch can be considered a one-time load.) For a one-time load, an SSIS package is probably the easiest to do. Copy one-for-one for all of the identical tables (don't forget to set Identity Insert on) ,then use a query that generates the info you want in the one new table from the two old tables as source, and upload that into the new trable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Kin for referencing the bcp tool. I was able to solve my problem using bcp.

The way to do that for me was to export the data as a query of joinging

```
bcp "select A.column1, B.column2 from A join B on A.BId = B.Id" queryout C:\temp\AJoinB.dat -n -S serverHostName -T
```

Then

```
bcp MyNewTable in C:\temp\AJoinB.dat -n -S serverHostName -T
```

And that did it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use bcp out and bulk insert to achieve what you are trying to do.

You can [use my script](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/55063/8783)

Create a folder `D:\BCP_OUT\` locally on the server where the bcp out files will reside.

```
/************************************************************************************************************************************************
Author      :   KIN SHAH    *********************************************************************************************************************
Purpose     :   Move data from one server to another or from one db to another *********************************************************************************************
DATE        :   05-28-2013  *********************************************************************************************************************
Version     :   1.0.0   *************************************************************************************************************************
RDBMS       :   MS SQL Server 2008R2 and 2012 & up  *************************************************************************************************
*************************************************************************************************************************************************/

-- save below output in a bat file by executing below in SSMS in TEXT mode. Review the OUTPUT and run the .bat file. This will create the bcp out files with data in them.
-- clean up: create a bat file with this command --> del D:\BCP_OUT\*.dat 

select '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe" '-- path to BCP.exe
        +  QUOTENAME(DB_NAME())+ '.'                                    -- Current Database
        +  QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID))+'.'            
        +  QUOTENAME(name)  
        +  ' out D:\BCP_OUT\'                                           -- Path where BCP out files will be stored
        +  REPLACE(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id),' ','') + '_' 
        +  REPLACE(name,' ','') 
        + '.dat -T -E -SSERVERNAME\INSTANCE -n'                         -- ServerName, -E will take care of Identity, -n is for Native Format
from sys.tables
where is_ms_shipped = 0 and name <> 'sysdiagrams'                       -- sysdiagrams is classified my MS as UserTable and we dont want it
and schema_name(schema_id) <> 'some_schema_exclude'                     -- Optional to exclude any schema 
order by schema_name(schema_id)                         



--- Execute this on the destination server.database from SSMS.
--- Make sure the change the @Destdbname and the bcp out path as per your environment.

declare @Destdbname sysname
set @Destdbname = 'destination_database_Name'               -- Destination Database Name where you want to Bulk Insert in
select 'BULK INSERT '                                       -- Remember Tables **must** be present on destination Database
        +  QUOTENAME(@Destdbname)+ '.'
        +  QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID))+'.' 
        +  QUOTENAME(name) 
        + ' from ''D:\BCP_OUT\'                             -- Change here for bcp out path
        +  REPLACE(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id),' ','') + '_'
        +  REPLACE(name,' ','') 
        +'.dat'' 
        with (
        KEEPIDENTITY,
        DATAFILETYPE = ''native'',  
        TABLOCK
        )'  + char(10) 
        + 'print ''Bulk insert for '+REPLACE(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id),' ','') + '_'+  REPLACE(name,' ','')+' is done... '''+ char(10)+'go' 
from sys.tables
where is_ms_shipped = 0 and name <> 'sysdiagrams'           -- sysdiagrams is classified my MS as UserTable and we dont want it
and schema_name(schema_id) <> 'some_schema_exclude'         -- Optional to exclude any schema 
order by schema_name(schema_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Import/Export in the SSMS for transferring data (right-click a database in Object Explorer -> Tasks -> Import Data... / Export Data ...) - pick SQL connection to DBv1 as a source and DBv2 as a destination and select objects to be transferred along with mapping in the next steps.

[Here's Import/Export tutorial by Ray Barley](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/203/simple-way-to-import-data-into-sql-server/)

For where you have a difference in the schema you might try creating a view that would translate in the source table according to your new destination in the DBv2 and in the Import/Export dialog map that to appropriate object(s) in the destination.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest method for doing this would be to restore a copy of `DBv1` as `DBv2`, then alter the table to be retained by adding a column, then copying the data from the table to be dropped into the new column.

For example, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.retain
(
    retain_id int NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    ...cols...
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.to_be_dropped
(
    to_be_dropped int NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , retain_id int NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY 
        REFERENCES dbo.retain(retain_id)
    , someData varchar(30) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE dbo.retain
ADD someData varchar(30) NOT NULL;

UPDATE dbo.retain
SET someData = tbd.someData
FROM dbo.retain r
    INNER JOIN dbo.to_be_dropped tbd ON r.retain_id = tbd.retain_id;
```

Once you've validated the data has been correctly copied, simple drop the unneeded table:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.to_be_dropped;
```